# ngIf show based on dropdown value - Angular 2

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-ng-if

I have one parent component that contains couple different components.
In "project" component (child), I have dropdown from which user can pick any available project.

What I need is other components to be created with ngIf when any project is selected from dropdown.

As you can see from here, I already placed ngIf in parent component for components that I want to be affected.

```
<div class="tab tab-style">

<ribbon-item style="width:10%;" [title]="'Load/Save Project'">
    <project></project>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item style="width:12%;" [title]="'Project settings'" *ngIf="showComponent">
    <project-settings></project-settings>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item style="width:23%;" [title]="'Environment'" *ngIf="showComponent">
    <environment></environment>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item class="pd-width" [title]="'Project dates'" *ngIf="showComponent">
    <project-dates></project-dates>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>
```

And this is "project" component with dropdown.

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
<select #projectSelect class="custom-select custom-select-project" (change)="loadProject(projectSelect.value)">
    <option selected disabled>Open projects</option>
    <option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]=project.id>{{project.name}}</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-main" (click)="createNewProject()">New project</button>
<button class="btn-main">Save project</button> 
<button class="btn-main">Save as</button>
```

How can I check when user pick any project, and then show other components in parent.

Comment: You have different child components, (all siblings), which you want to be shown if a drop-down in one of the child components has a specific value, is that right?

Comment: Yes, just like that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use output from your project component. 
The flow will be as defined below:

Step-1. change in parent component for project component as :

```
 `<project (projectSelected) = "projectSelected($event)"></Project>`
```

Step-2:  In your project component defined the output variable as :

```
@Output() projectSelected: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Step-3: In  loadProject add below line :

```
this.projectSelected.emit(id); // selected value from dropdown
```

step-4 : In parent component defined function as :

```
projectSelected(projectId) {
 this.showComponent = true;
}
```

Comment: ...is this ok? 

`loadProject( id ) {
        this.projectService.getById( id ).subscribe(
            response => { this.projectService.projectLoaded$.emit( response ) },
            error => { console.error( error ); }
        );
        
        this.answerChanged.emit($event.value);
    }`

I got error that answerChanged is not defined and Cannot find name '$event' @pritesh agrawal

Comment: my mistake i copied thee addAswer from my local code , it  should be projectSelected ,  also you can use id . I updated the answer.

Comment: If I want to do this same thing, but for other component to hide, that is not sibling, what should I change?